# Distinctive traits of the functional languages

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming, erlang, clojure

It is known that all functional languages share some basic properties like using functions as basic building block for programs with all the consequences like using recursion instead of iteration. However, some fundamental differences also exist. Lisp uses a single representation for both Lisp code and data, while ML has no standard representation of ML code. Erlang has a built-in actor-based concurrency. Haskell has monads.  Haskell makes a distinction in the static type system between pure and impure functions; ML does not.

What are the distinctive **fundamental** differences between other functional languages (Clojure, F#, Arc, any other)? By fundamental I mean something which influences the way you develop in this language, and *not* for example, whether it is integrated with some wide-spread runtime.

Comment: Most functional languages _do_ have a distinction between code and data. Lisp is atypical in this respect.

Comment: My bad, haven't looked deep enough and made this wrong conclusion of Lisp and Erlang.

Comment: I am unclear what the question is.  Are you asking e.g. "what sets F# apart from Clojure", or else what are you asking?  Are you looking for information about specific languages, or FP languages in general?

Comment: Yep, exactly something like "what sets F# apart from Clojure". E.g. Haskell being set apart from Lisp by having monads.

Comment: Monads are distinctive, but I think of them as a side-effect of more fundamental traits: monads become useful in a lazy, pure language, and require higher-order datatypes.

Comment: Excellent question but: "ML" refers to a family of languages spanning four decades and OCaml (which is the latest ML) does actually have a standard representation of OCaml code. The phase "Haskell has monads" is misleading: monads are found in many languages but they are much more prevalent in Haskell as a workaround for the prohibition of side effects.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

- [*lazy* vs. *eager*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) (aka *non-strict* vs. *strict* or *call-by-need* vs. *call-by-value*): are function arguments evaluated before the function application, or after, or never?
- [*pure* vs. *impure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science)): does the language allow functions to have side effects? Does it have mutable references?
- [*static* vs. *dynamic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system): does the language check types at compile time or runtime?
- [*algebraic datatypes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type): does the language support pattern matching over variant types?
- [*metaprogramming*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming): does the language provide a powerful code generation system?
- [*concurrency*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency) and [*parallelism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism): are threads/processes a first-class abstraction? Does the language make it easy to run multiple computations at the same time?
- *"exotic" types*: how expressive is the static type system? GADTs? Dependent types? Linear types? System F?

Only the first two items are really unique to functional languages (i.e., almost all imperative languages are eager and impure).

Comment: Don't throw "strong/weak" in with "static/dynamic" typing, make it a point of itself.

Comment: Strong vs. weak is ill-defined. I consider static strong and dynamic weak. YMMV.

Comment: Static typing just means that types are determined at compile time, dynamic typing means that types are determined at run time.  Strong typing means that type mismatches are always errors, weak typing allows implicit conversion.  These distinctions are orthogonal.  For example, C has weak static typing, Common Lisp has strong dynamic typing,  Perl has weak dynamic typing, and Haskell has strong static typing.

Comment: @Svante I've fixed the terminology in the answer -- it'll come up once someone approves it.

Answer (score 14):

I like Chris Conway's answer that states some important axes that help classify different functional languages.

In terms of features of specific languages, I'll pick **[F#](http://fsharp.net)** to call out some features not found in many other FPLs:

- **Active Patterns**: a number of FPLs have algebraic data types and pattern-matching, but the F# feature called 'active patterns' lets you define new patterns that allow you to use pattern-matching syntax on arbitrary data.
- **Computation expressions**: F# has some beautiful syntactic sugar for authoring monadic code; though the type system cannot express higher-kinded polymorphism (no abstraction over type constructors) so you can't write code for an arbitrary monad M, the code you can write for a fixed monad is very cool, and people write some great comprehensions in the seq{} or async{} monads.
- **Quotations**: the usual 'code as data for metaprogramming' bit, though F# has an expressive static type system and rich syntax, and I'm not sure how many non-lisps can do this.

In terms of general classification, F# is

- **eager** (strict, call-by-value; but 'lazy' is a keyword & library and using seq/IEnumerable for some laziness is a common strategy)
- **impure** (though syntax biases you towards a purer-by-default style)
- **static** (with type inference, so F# often 'feels like scripting', only with type safety)

Your question is phrased in a way with clear bias against some extra-language pragmatics (e.g. what runtime does it integrate with), but you also ask what "influences the way you develop", and these things do influence that:

- Visual Studio integration means a **great editing experience** (e.g. Intellisense)
- Visual Studio integration means a **great debugging experience** (e.g. breakpoints/tracepoints, locals, immediate window, ...)
- **REPL** for scripting or UI-on-the-fly is hotness (fsi.exe command-line, or "F# Interactive" integrated in VS)
- .NET integration means for most 'X' there's already a library to do that
- side tools like FsLex/FsYacc, and integration with MSBuild which makes 'build system' easy

(I think that trying to separate a language from its runtime and tooling is a mostly academic exercise.)

So there's a description of lot of distinctive features of one particular language of which I am a fan.  I hope others might post similar answers that call out distinctive features of other individual languages.

Comment: Objective Caml and Haskell both have very interesting quasiquoting mechanisms.

Comment: Scala has excellent support for custom pattern matching. Scala, Clojure and Haskell have the build systems sbt, Leiningen and Cabal respectively. Metaprogramming is supported with MetaOCaml and Template Haskell. Other than the Visual Studio integration, F#'s features aren't at all unique.

Answer (score 9):

1. Non-strict vs strict evaluation.
2. Static vs dynamic typing.
3. Structural vs nominal static typing.
   OCaml is the only language I can
   think of with structural typing (in both objects and polymorphic variants),
   which closes the gap with dynamic
   typing by removing the need to
   define many types (e.g. variant
   types).
4. Hindley-Milner derivatives vs other static type inference algorithms. SML, OCaml, Haskell and F# use type inference algorithms based upon Hindley-Milner whereas Scala has only local type inference (like C# 3) and requires many more annotations to compile. (Haskell code is often full of type annotations at the function level but most are unnecessary and are added for documentation and to help the compiler in the presence of errors).
5. Pattern matching vs manual
   deconstruction. SML, OCaml, F#,
   Haskell, Mathematica and Scheme
   automate the deconstruction of
   values.
6. Closed sum types vs only open sum types. SML, OCaml, F# and Haskell allow closed/sealed algebraic types to be defined to strengthen static typing by conveying more specific constraints implicitly. OCaml and F# also allow open sum types whereas SML does not and Haskell requires an elaborate workaround (described by Oleg Kiselyov).
7. Bounded-time patterns. Pattern matching is very fast in SML and (vanilla) OCaml but has unknown performance in F# due to active patterns and even unknown asymptotic complexity in Mathematica.
8. On-the-fly compilation to native
   code. F#, Lisp and Scheme allow code
   to be generated, compiled and
   executed efficiently at run-time.
9. Macros. OCaml, Mathematica, Lisp and
   Scheme are extensible languages.
10. Standardized vs proprietary. SML, Haskell 2010, Common Lisp and Scheme are standardized languages whereas OCaml, Erlang, F# and Mathematica are proprietary.

Comment: Huh? OCaml and Erlang are proprietary?

Comment: I think Jon means "does not have a published standard", not proprietary in their implementations.

Comment: "proprietary" does not equal "not standardized". These are orthogonal attributes. Plenty of open-source languages are non-proprietary (by definition) but do not have published standards. You can also have proprietary languages that have published standards (C# on .Net being a prominent example)

Answer (score 5):

There are many differences but **only two differences I'd categorize as fundamental** in that they make a big difference to your development:

1. Dynamically typed vs static, polymorphic type system with algebraic data types and type inference.  A static type system restricts code somewhat, but has many advantages:

   - Types are documentation that is checked by the compiler.
   - The type system helps you choose what code to write next, and when you're not sure just what to write, the type system helps you easily and quickly rule out many alternatives.
   - A powerful, modern, polymorphic type system is unreasonably good at detecting small, silly, time-wasting bugs.
2. Lazy evaluation as the default everywhere vs lazy evaluation restricted to carefully controlled constructs.

   - Lazy vs eager has tremendous implications for your ability to predict and understand the time and space costs of your programs.
   - In a fully lazy language, you can completely decouple *production* of data from decisions about what to do with data once produced.  This is especially important for search problems as it becomes much easier to modularize and reuse code.

Answer (score 3):

**Functional Programming is a style, not a language construct**

Most functional languages have some common principles:

- Immutable objects
- Closures and anonymous functions
- Generic algorithms
- Continuations

But the most important principle is that they usually force you to write in a functional style. You can program in a functional style in most any language. C# could be considered "functional" if you write code like that, as could any other language.

Comment: modules and functors are not necessary, but common as well.

Comment: I would include functions as a value.

Comment: Yes, but I wonder what are distinctive properties between different functional languages, and not between functional and non-functional ones.

Comment: well, definitly, functions as value as rampion mentions.  Type systems, pattern matching, and list comprehension are other good character as well.

Comment: Depends who you ask. I would say that first-class lexical closures make a language functional. Haskell programmers often use the completely different idea that functional programming means only purely functional, i.e. essentially just Haskell today.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamental properties?

- Functional Purity (lack of side-effects)
- As a tie-in from the above, lack of state.
- Pattern-matching in functions

The first is beautiful, the second is an ugly side-effect of the former (pun intended).

The real-world compensation for lack-of-state is what I find to be the biggest differentiator between functional languages.

Those few things give lots of freebies.  Most of the time, languages handle memoization.

Comment: but most FP languages aren't pure

Comment: The extent to which a language can be said to facilitate FP is directly proportional to its purity.

Comment: there isn't a lack of state, it's just that state is stored elsewhere, often on the stack.

Comment: Hmm, the extent a language is "functional", by pure definition, is mainly related to it's higher order function/functions as value capabilities. If a language makes it hard to define and return functions, then it's less functional, no?

Answer (score 2):

When you say code as data you are referring to a language where the code is represented in a data structure.  This is referred to as [Homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) and it usually only true for languages that are lisp dialects or something close to it.  Haskell, Erlang and Scala are not Homoiconic, Clojure is.

Clojure's fundamental differentiators are:

1. It has a Software Transactional Memory system, which makes shared state concurrent programming easier
2. It is a Lisp, unlike Haskell or Erlang, therefore all code is data, which allows you to make what look likes changes to the language itself at runtime through the macro system
3. It runs on the JVM, which means you have direct access to all Java libraries
4. Clojure data structures implement Java interfaces such as Collection, List, Map, Runnable and Callable where appropriate.  Strings are just Java Strings, Numbers are Java Integers and Doubles.  This means Clojure data structures can be passed directly to Java libraries without any bridging or translation

Comment: Code is data != Homoiconicity. For example, camlp4 provides code as data but it is not necessarily homoiconic because it support arbitrary syntaxes.

Comment: Haskell does have modules for STM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory#Haskell